# How to search a row for cell value(s) then output the header?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-if, textjoin

I'm new here and trying to automate. I have a work roster and would like for it to output who are on duty on a daily basis. Ideally. it would check today's date then search the corresponding table row for the relevant personnel each day.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tFg4.png)

Spreadsheet: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fiOt8kT0judDJQNEZQkDxMiRS-V1gVuP9Oy2E7ECYuo/edit?usp=sharing)

Desired output:

On `today's date`, AM shifts are `Person 1 (duty)` `Person 2`, PM shifts are `Person 3`

Current formula:

```
="On "&textjoin("",TRUE,B7)&": AM shifts are "
&OFFSET(INDEX(A3:E3,MATCH("AM Duty",A3:E3,0)),1-row(vlookup(today(),A1:E5,2,0)),0)&" (duty) "
&OFFSET(INDEX(A3:E3,MATCH("AM Reg",A3:E3,0)),1-row(vlookup(today(),A1:E5,2,0)),0)
&", PM shifts are "
&OFFSET(INDEX(A3:E3,MATCH("PM Reg",A3:E3,0)),1-row(vlookup(today(),A1:E5,2,0)),0)
```

Some problems with formula:

1. Row needs to adjust according to today's date as it goes down the list, currently it's hardcoded A3:E3
2. Unsure how to capture repeated *AM Reg* in each row

Not sure if I'm overcomplicating things here, and open to better solutions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: any more insight on assigning (Prime) vs (duty) ??

Comment: and what about the sick? should they be mentioned too?

Comment: oops! Prime was a typo, it should just be duty. And no need to mention the sick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(TODAY(), "On dd mmmm yy: A\M \s\hift\s ar\e ")&
 TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(TODAY(), A2:E5, {2,3,4,5}, ), "AM Duty"), B1:E1&" (duty), ", ))&
 TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(TODAY(), A2:E5, {2,3,4,5}, ), "AM Reg"),  B1:E1, ))&" and PM shifts are "&
 TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(TODAY(), A2:E5, {2,3,4,5}, ), "PM Duty"), B1:E1&" (duty), ", ))&
 TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(TODAY(), A2:E5, {2,3,4,5}, ), "PM Reg"),  B1:E1, )))
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! Have modified it to suit the actual dataset and it works! Great tip on regex too, I've learnt something